# Facebook Pages (/me/accounts) access_token Expiration?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

Bear with me, I know `access_token` questions have been asked a thousand times but I can't seem to find an answer to this specific question.

**Is there an expiration date for *Facebook Page* (not app, not user) access tokens?**

I know that:

- `offline_access` has been deprecated.
- I can request a 60-day user `access_token`

**Step 1:** I use Facebook Connect and I get a **user** `access_token` which has the  `manage_pages` permission (by default, this token expires in 2 hours, extendable to 60 days)

**Step 2:** I then call `/me/accounts` and get an array of the user's pages each one with a listed **page** `access_token`

**Step 3:** I can use the **page** `access_token` in subsequent API calls to do things like posting to the user's page.

I need users to be able to schedule page updates to happen in the future (when they will not be online).

So again the question is:

- What is the expiration date of the **page** `access_token` returned from `/me/accounts`?

**If the expiration date is tied to something, what is it tied to?**

- Expiration date of the **user** `access_token` used when requesting `/me/accounts`?
- 60-days from when the request is made to `/me/accounts`?

I apologize for my confusion, the Facebook documentation seems to fall extremely short in describing these access tokens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just created a brand new app.  Ensured the deprecate offline access was enabled.  Went to explorer, found my new app in the dropdown, granted myself manage_pages, went to me/accounts grabbed one of the page access tokens, and then linted it. Whew! 1 hour expiration.

**EDIT**

I tried exchanging that 1 hour page token and I got an error from fb.

I went back to the user access token, and exchanged it for a 60 day one. Verified in the linter that it was a 60 day.  Went back to me/accounts and grabbed one of the page access tokens and linted it.  Suprise!  Got a 60 day token from there.

So the moral of the story is, you cannot exchange page tokens, only user tokens.  But with a 60 day user token you can get a 60 day page token.  :)

Comment: Genius! You know your way around Facebook's tools. Thank you!

Comment: Follow up question: is there a way to get the data returned from Facebook's Linter from the graph api? E.g. by hitting https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/TOKEN or something?

Comment: I know of `me/permissions` to get the list of perms for the current access token, but it doesn't include any expiration information.  If I come across something...I'll come back and report here.

Comment: I guess the next question is, can a 60 day token be gotten from that page access token?

Comment: Notes above about the 60 day tokens.

Comment: You might have to uninstall/reinstall the app so the access token updates correctly.